# Cannot trigger controller event on Razor Page [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm learning ASP.net and I'm using the razor pages.
I'm trying to connect a button to a Controller but when I click the button it just refresh the page.

Accounting.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "LogOut", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <a class="logoutLblPos">
                <input type="submit" id="logoutbtn" value="LogOff" asp-controller="LogOutController">
            </a>
        }
```

LogoutController.cs:

```
public class LogoutController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It is all afternoon that I'm trying to figure out why it is not working and I googled a lot.
Can you please provide an explanation also.

PS: I trying [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] already.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Michael, any update about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectToPage` is the syntax in `Razor Pages`,`Razor Pages` is an application in Asp.net core.

And your project looks completely an `MVC` project, because `Razor Pages` does not contain `Controller`.

For a detailed description of `Razor Pages`, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

You can modify your code as follows to make your application work normally:

Accounting.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Logout", FormMethod.Post))
{
<a class="logoutLblPos">
    <input type="submit" id="logoutbtn" value="LogOff">
</a>
}
```

LogoutController.cs(Use `[HttpPost]` and `RedirectToAction`):

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
      public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    { 
        //...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public IActionResult Accounting()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks! I just tried as you suggested but it is not working. I set a breakpoint on the '{' as you did but it doesn't even call the funcion LogOff.

Comment: Delete the `asp-controller="LogOutController"` code in your view,and `logoff` action must be `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: If there are still problems, you can share your project structure with us.

Answer (score -1):

In your LogoutController change LogOff attribute to [HttpPost] and in Accounting.cshtml remove: asp-controller="LogOutController" also try renaming LogOut in the Html.Beginform... Logout <- notice the small O

Comment: Please also realise in your LogOff method you are redirecting to Index so be sure you have an html page called Index.cshtml in you views under the logout folder.